# What is the equivalent of `paramType: form` in the Core API of DJango Rest Swagger 2?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-swagger

In the old django rest swagger, you can specify `paramType: form` in the docstring of the viewset and retrieve the parameter via `request.data['param_x']`, as follows:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
  """
  Make something cool
  ---
  parameters:
  - name: param_x
    required: true
    paramType: form
  """

  def list(self, request):
    param_x = request.data['param_x']
    # do something cool...
```

In the newer version, I usually use `coreapi.Field` to specify the properties of the parameters, and set the param type to the `location` argument key (e.g. `core.api.Field(name='param_x', location='query')`). All the available location values are discussed in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#core-api). However, none of them seemed to be doing what I expected (not even `location='form'`).

How do you set the parameter type to `form` with the newer version of django rest swagger? I'm probably missing something here.